# Powering 5V Laser with Raspberry Pi 4 GPIO Pins

Tags: transistors, resistors, raspberry-pi, gpio, laser

I am powering a 5V, 5mW laser that draws ~30mA (KY-008) with a GPIO on my Raspberry Pi 4. From my research, GPIO pins have a voltage output of 3.3V, so I'm not supposed to be doing this. Unfortunately, I do not have the option of hooking the laser up to the 5V pin on my RPi, and I need to be able to control it, so the GPIO's are my only options.

I have been doing this for weeks now and the only issue I notice is a drop in the power output of the laser. I plan on soldering the wires (S pin of the laser module to GPIO 8 and - pin of laser module to GND) soon. Is there something I can solder in between those connections to improve performance and possible save my RPi from destruction, like resistors or a transistor? I saw something online about how with a small enough current draw requirement, the overstep in voltage might not be an issue, which I'm hoping is the case for this.

Comment: "`I am powering a 5V, 5mW laser... [with a] GPIO pins have a voltage output of 3.3V, so I'm not supposed to be doing this... I have been doing this for weeks now`" This isn't a good idea. You should refer to the datasheet whether this something you're able to do. To protect your RPi from possible overcurrent, you could use a fuse in series with the GPIO pin. Alternatively, there also exists a device called an "optoisolator" that can be used to isolate the GPIO from your laser device.

Comment: @KingDuken could you recommend something to make them compatible? I know voltage dividers are a viable option but I'm not sure what specs I would need.

Comment: It's uncertain _why_ you cannot use the 5V since you mentioned that you can't but I would recommend an external 5V source to use with a transistor so that way your GPIO can "turn on and off" the 5V rail.

Comment: @KingDuken the 5V pins are occupied by servo motors.